# Extract XML Tag Values (Based on a Flag) Using Batch

Tags: xml, batch-file, xml-parsing

I am a beginner in writing batch scripts and your help on this is very much apreciated.

Below is the xml and I need to extract all names whose flag is "on" to a txt file. There are several other category tag instances.

```
<Head>
   <Category
      name="RIVERTD"
      flag="on"
      location="SG002">
    </Category>
   <Category
      name="BRETRED"
      flag="on"
      location="IT213">
    </Category>
   <Category
      name="AMERAND"
      flag="off"
      location="US212">
   </Category>
</Head>
```

So, the output I'm looking is as below

```
RIVERTD
BRETRED
```

I tried using below code

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set input="CP.xml"
set output="Names.txt"

if exist %output% del %output%
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n /c:"name=" %input%') do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  call :parseLine
  endlocal
)
type %output%
exit /b

:parseLine
set "ln2=!ln:*name=!"
if "!ln2!"=="!ln!" exit /b
for /f tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%B in ("!ln2!") do (
  setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
  >>%output% echo(%%B
  endlocal
)
set "ln=!ln2!"
goto :parseLine
```

This gives me the result

```
RIVERTD
BRETRED
AMERAND
```

However this code doesn't filter the names based on flag. I'm a beginner. Kindly help to add filter based on flag. Many thanks.

Comment: [This is not an answer.]  Who is holding that gun to your head and making you try to solve this problem with a .BAT file?  If you can somehow overpower them and regain your freedom, look into solving this problem with a more suitable tool like XSLT or an XPath library.  Or perhaps we should send in a hostage negotiator to try to resolve the situation?  Please advise.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen: I don't understand people that criticize Batch files and don't know its features. I am pretty sure that no XSLT nor XPath solution, neither any other language/package solution for that matter, could be simpler than my 6-lines Batch solution below...

Comment: @Aacini, you could be right.  (But for comparison, the XPath expression to retrieve the names here is `Category[@flag='on']/@name`; this does not include non-XPath overhead like selecting the file, of course, so in practice it's not necessarily always a one-liner.)

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen: I assume your XPath example does not include the output of the names either, so I think that the Batch line `if "!flag!" equ "on" echo !name!` is much clearer for anyone. I see no reason to use such cryptic XPath code, unless someone "is holding that gun to your head and making you try to solve this problem with" it...  ;-)  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may be solved with a very interesting trick!:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(for /F "tokens=1,2 delims== " %%a in (CP.xml) do (
   if "%%~b" neq "" set %%a=%%~b
   if /I "!flag!" equ "on" echo !name!& set flag=
)) > Names.txt
```

**EDIT**: *Some explanations adeded*

The file have several lines, but the OP look for lines that have the form of an assignment, like these:

```
  name="RIVERTD"
  flag="on"

  name="BRETRED"
  flag="on"

  name="AMERAND"
  flag="off"
```

My program does NOT check for any name, but execute any line with a value after the equal sign as an assignment. This way, when my program process previous lines, the result is equivalent to execute the following commands:

```
  set name="RIVERTD"
  set flag="on"

  set name="BRETRED"
  set flag="on"

  set name="AMERAND"
  set flag="off"
```

After that, just check if FLAG variable have the value "on"; if so, then the NAME variable have the target value, because it was assigned in previous line.

Antonio

Comment: @ajp: Explanation added, check it

Answer (score 3):

Here's the [**xpath.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat)  -small script that will allow you to get a xml  values by xpath expression without using external binaries:

```
call xpath.bat "CP.xml" "//Category[0]/@name"
call xpath.bat "CP.xml" "//Category[1]/@name"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "Name="
set "Flag="
set "Output=Names.txt"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%L in (`type "CP.xml"`) do (
    for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=    =<> " %%A in ('%%L') do (
        if /i "%%~A"=="name" set "Name=%%~B"
        if /i "%%~A"=="flag" set "Flag=%%~B"
        if /i "%%~A"=="/category" (
            if /i "!Flag!"=="on" echo.!Name!>>%Output%
            set "Name="
            set "Flag="
        )
    )
)

endlocal
pause
```