# Parse XML file for attribute from batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file, xml-parsing

I am parsing a XML file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
-->
<configuration>
   <settings>
      <connections>
            <connection name="name1" value="connection1" type="abc"/>
            <connection name="name2" value="connection2" type="def"/>
      </connections>
   </settings>
</configuration>
```

From the batch file, I prompt the user for connection name. I want to parse the XML get a connection with the specified name and get its value. So If user gives name1, I want to select connection1. I had the below code from [Extract XML Tag Values (Based on a Flag) Using Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902744/extract-xml-tag-values-based-on-a-flag-using-batch)

I am not familiar with for loop in (especially delimits, tokens) batch file, so I am not sure how this works and how to make it work for me.

```
(for /F "tokens=1,2 delims== " %%a in (connection.config) do (
   if "%%~b" neq "" set %%a=%%~b
   if /I "!name!" equ "%name%" echo !value!
))
```

Comment: +1 for just being insane enough to try to parse XML in a batch script.

Comment: -1 for not being sane enough to realise parsing xml in a batch script is bad idea. (only kidding)

Comment: have a look at [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), a set of command-line utilities that will save you from severe unhappiness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works, if you use the right tokens and delimiters:

```
@echo off&setlocal
for /F tokens^=2^,3^,5delims^=^<^"^= %%a in (connection.config) do (
   if "%%a" equ "connection name" echo(%%b %%c
)
```

Output is:

```
name1 connection1
name2 connection2
```

Comment: What is the purpose of escaping everything like that. Also, why isn't there a " before Tokens?

Comment: You can use double quotes to escape something or as delimiters, but not for both.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the [**xpath.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat)  -small script that will allow you to get a xml  values by xpath expression without using external binaries:

```
call xpath.bat "connection.config" "//connection/@name"
call xpath.bat "connection.config" "//connection/@value"
```

to assign this to a variable:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('xpath.bat "connection.config" "//connection/@value"') do set "connection_value=%%#"
echo %connection_value%
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "name=name1"
SET "connection="
SET "type="

for /F "tokens=5,7delims==/ " %%a in (
 'findstr /c:"<connection name=\"%name%\"" ^<connection.config'
 ) do SET connection=%%~a&SET type=%%~b

ECHO connection=%connection%
ECHO TYPE      =%type%
```

Finding the data line which contains the literal string "\" escapes `"`) then set connection to the 5th (and type for good measure) from the seventh token of the data line

```
        <connection name="name1" value="connection1" type="abc"/>
```

using `=`, `/` and `[space]` as delimiters.