# parse xml using a batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file

i have been working with this idea as listed here

[Parse XML file for attribute from batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174161/parse-xml-file-for-attribute-from-batch-file)

But i cant comment to ask for more questions so i am asking for more help and this is not really a duplicate cause i changed several things

So my channelGuide.xml looks like this

```
<Guide>
   <listings>
      <channels>
         <channel ID='1' name='big bang' url='http://v.com/bigbang' quality='best' />
         <channel ID='2' name='AMerican Dad' url='http://v.com/americandad' quality='best' />
      </channels>
   </listings>
</Guide>
```

now my .bat file looks like this:

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F tokens^=2^-9^,7delims^=^<^"^= %%a in (channelGuide.xml) do (
   if "%%a" equ "channel ID" echo(%%b %%c %%d %%e>>"%~d0%~p0\channelListings.txt"
)
```

but for some reason my .tx is coming back like this:

```
'1' name 'big bang' url 'http://v.com/bigbang' quality 'best' />
'2' name 'AMerican Dad' url 'http://v.com/americandad' quality 'best' />
```

I  do not want the single quotes or anything but to look exactly like this:

```
1 big bang http://v.com/bigbang best
2 AMerican Dad http://v.com/americandad best
```

Comment: XML has some limitations which can break batch file solutions - read about them here: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=36470#p36470

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

for /F "tokens=2,4,6,8delims='" %%a in (q25617807.txt) do (
   if "%%d" neq "" echo(%%a %%b %%c %%d
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q25617807.txt` containing your data for my testing and removed the file redirection to suit my testing regime.

---

Explanation, using a single data line provided

```
   <channel ID='1' name='big bang' url='http://v.com/bigbang' quality='best' />
```

The data line is tokenised using the single-quote as a delimiter into tokens

1. <kbd>Spaces</kbd><channel ID=
2. 1
3. <kbd>Space</kbd>name=
4. big bang
5. <kbd>Space</kbd>url=
6. http://v.com/bigbang
7. <kbd>Space</kbd>quality=
8. best
9. <kbd>Space</kbd>/>

Of these, tokens 2,4,6 and 8 are selected, so they get applied in sequence to %%a..%%d.

It's unlikely that another line would contain 4 strings in single-quotes (and not shown in original data) so simply filtering for "%%d" not being empty should be sufficient.

Time? After 13 years' unemployment, I've that in spades....

Comment: if you have time maybe explain what things are doing here so i can learn more.  and thank you for your help

Comment: might be problematic, if there are other lines with 8 tokens (or more) in the xml (which is not unlikely)

Comment: @Stephan : certainly. Would be easy to fix if required by changing the `tokens` assignment and analysing another token or tokens to gate the output. Not ss you say, unlikely - but possible. More likely that the program title may contain a single quote, but that would indicate a command of the language far beyond the apparent capabilities of the `txt` generation, sadly...

Comment: what if i was looking to just get info back for a certain id like id #2 ??

Comment: This is starting to become a saga. To extrat simply id=2, then modify the `if` statement to `if "%%d" neq "" if "%%a" equ "2"...` That is, when both the fourth field exists *and* the first is equal to `2`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the [xpath.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat) - script that can get a value from xml file by given xpath:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('xpath.bat "chanel.xml" "//channel[0]/@name"') do (
  set name1=%%#
)

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('xpath.bat "chanel.xml" "//channel[0]/@url"') do (
  set url1=%%#
)

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('xpath.bat "chanel.xml" "//channel[0]/@quality"') do (
  set quality1=%%#
)

echo %name1% %url1% %quality1%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,5,7,9 delims='<" %%a in (channellistings.xml) do if "%%b"=="channel ID=" echo %%c %%d %%e %f
```

you should consider to delimit your output with (for example) `;` instead of a space. Might be easier afterwards to process it. (for example reading it with excel)