# Parse string in batch srcipt

Tags: batch-file

Can somebody help me in parsing the following string in batch script?
I don't have much idea about batch command.

```
<ConnectionStatus xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs
d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <WiFi>
    <WiFiAdapters>
      <WiFiAdapter Id="{1BF5A58C-DC42-4E79-8861-ECB6081D7211}" NetworkName="iRoa
mX" ConnStatus="Connected" Inherited="False" />
    </WiFiAdapters>
  </WiFi>
  <Ethernet>
    <EnetAdapters />
  </Ethernet>
  <MobileBroadband>
    <MBAdapters />
  </MobileBroadband>
  <DSL>
    <DSLAdapters />
  </DSL>
  <Dial>
    <DialAdapters />
  </Dial>
</ConnectionStatus>
```

Comment: If I want to get the NetworkName in the above xml. How do i parse it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse XML file for attribute from batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174161/parse-xml-file-for-attribute-from-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

save this with `.bat` extension:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off


    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*

    exit /b %errorlevel%

@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

var objDoc = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument");
objDoc.load(WScript.Arguments.Item(0));

var objNode = objDoc.selectSingleNode("//"+WScript.Arguments.Item(1));
WScript.Echo(objNode.text);
```

and execute:

```
xmlscript.bat network.xml "WiFiAdapter/@NetworkName"
```